# Can $f_1(x, y)-f_2(u, v)$ be written as $g(x-u, y-v)$?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, nonlinear-analysis

when I do some calculation on the basic theory of diffractive neural networks,the question behind blocks my way.It's a pure math that i want to know, $f_1 (x, y)$ and $f_2(u, v)$ are both nonlinear functions $(f(ax + by) != af(x) + bf(y)$ where $a$ and $b$ are both constants). Is there any set of functions satisfy $f_1 (x, y) - f_2(u, v) = g(x-u, y-v)$? If not, I would appreciate that if you can provide a proof. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about continous functions defined $\mathbb{R}$, this is not possible. Proof:

Set
$$
x=a,y=b,u=0,v=0 \Rightarrow f_1(a,b)-f_2(0,0)=g(a,b)\\
x=0,y=0,u=a,v=b \Rightarrow f_1(0,0)-f_2(a,b)=g(-a,-b)\\
x=0,y=0,u=0,v=0 \Rightarrow f_1(0,0)-f_2(0,0)=g(0,0)
$$
We can express $f_1,f_2$ completely in terms of $g$. Inserting in the original equation yields
$$
g(x,y)+g(u,v)-g(0,0)=g(x+u,y+v)
$$
From here we need to check that $g$ is in fact linear. The easiest way I thought of assumes that $g$ is differentiable but I am certain this assumption can be relaxed if necessary.
$$
g(x+u,y+v)-g(x,y)=g(u,v,)-g(0,0)\\
\Rightarrow Dg(x,y)[(u,v)]=Dg(0,0)[(u,v)]
$$
So the derivate everywhere in any direction is equal to the derivative at zero implying $g$ is linear. Inserting back yields $f_1,f_2$ linear in even stricter way you suggested, namely $f(x,y)=ax+by+c$.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question.It's quite help.

Comment: A fantastic proof